# Link between wordpress plugin directory and wpackagist.org

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, composer-php, wpackagist

Is there any link between [wordpress plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php) and the packages found on [wpackagist.org](http://wpackagist.org) because if I use the search box writing the name of the plugin, I won't find anything? The seach seem to be case sensitive and sometimes I can't find what I need even if I don't write the full name.

For example if I want to install [YITH WooCommerce Ajax Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search/) I expected a button on this page which links to the package found on [wpackagist.org](http://wpackagist.org) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after many searches I managed to find the link between the wordpress plugin directory and wpackagist.org.

**Each wordpress theme and plugin has a unique slug. You can use that slug to search theme/plugin on wpackagist.org.**

You can find the slug of the plugin/theme directly in the url of the page. So for example if you want to find the slug of:

```
Black Studio TinyMCE Widget (Plugin)
Url  => https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/
Slug => black-studio-tinymce-widget

MH Magazine lite (Theme)
Url  => https://wordpress.org/themes/mh-magazine-lite/
Slug => mh-magazine-lite
```

After this you can search on wpackagist.org using this slugs and you will get the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a direct link available. Nor can you copy-paste the name from one to the other to search.

For example, it seems that the YITH WooCommerce Ajax Search plugin can be found if you search for '[yith-woocommerce](http://wpackagist.org/search?q=yith-woocommerce)' on wpackagist (or '[yith-woocommerce-ajax-search](http://wpackagist.org/search?q=yith-woocommerce-ajax-search)' more specifically).

Searching for the packages on wpackagist using just bare words (e.g. '[yith woocommerce](http://wpackagist.org/search?q=yith%20woocommerce)') seems to yield no results unfortunately.

The install page on the wordpress plugin directory for this particular plugin unfortunately only documents how to install from a zip archive.

Comment: Yes but how did you find out that you have to search by "'yith-woocommerce-ajax-search" in order to get that specific plugin? How should I know the exact keyword to search for in case I need other plugins ?